# kotlin safe and non-null operation

Tags: kotlin, null-check, kotlin-null-safety

```
if (intent.extras?.getBoolean(AppConstants.KEY_IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION) == true) {
    val intent = Intent(
        this, SplashScreen::class.java
    ).apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
} else {
    finish()
}
```

What if intent.extras is null. If its null what will happen to the statement

> if (intent.extras?.getBoolean(AppConstants.KEY_IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION)
> == true)

Comment: Then `intent.extras?.getBoolean(AppConstants.KEY_IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION)` is null, and null is not true, so the expression is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?.` in Kotlin is a simple *null check*: Taking this into consideration, the output of the `if (...)` would simply be `false`, on `intent.extras` being *null*.

For better understandability of the `?.` operator, I've written the same if statement in java below:

`if (intent.extras != null && intent.extras.getBoolean(...) == true) {...}`

If you'd like to create custom logic right after the `?.`, you can do so, by using the elvis operator `?:`. The elvis is nothing but a "ternary-null-check".

Comment: Java equivalent is actually `Bundle extras = intent.extras; if ((extras != null ? extras.getBoolean(...) : null) == true) {...}`.